# dependent SQL subquery returns too few rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery

I have a list of sales for hundreds of brands by shop and I want to get the TOP 100 brands per shop by sales.

For some unknown reason, it returns only 99 brands per shop. (In the source table there are more than 900 brands per each shop.)

That's my query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT SHOP, BRAND, SALES
FROM dbo.[DATA] AS D
WHERE (BRAND IN
   (SELECT TOP (100) WITH TIES BRAND
        FROM DATA
        WHERE (SHOP= D.SHOP)
        ORDER BY SALES DESC
    )
)
ORDER BY BRAND, SALES DESC
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `dbo` prefix and the non-standard ( `[..]`) "quoting" style

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved by the following query

```
SELECT Q.SHOP
     , Q.BRAND
     , Q.SALES
FROM (
    SELECT SHOP
         , BRAND
         , SALES
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SHOP ORDER BY SALES DESC) rn 
    FROM dbo.[DATA]
    ) Q
WHERE Q.rn <= 100
ORDER BY Q.BRAND, Q.SALES DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your approach works perfectly and is extremely fast. (9 million rows aggregated and sorted afterwards in 10 seconds!!!)